# Gráfico de análises acima de 1.000 análises

Tags: debate, filas-de-análise

Notei que ao realizar 1.000 análises, o gráfico de progresso é reiniciado¹.

- O novo gráfico possui algum limite?
- A coluna² próximo ao meio do gráfico representa algum marco?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: A coluna 2 é o 250 (neste caso, que tem uma meta de 250 e uma de 1000), uma das metas. a 1000 é a ultima meta, nao tem próximo marco

Comment: Mas é normal o gráfico reiniciar?

Comment: Eu **acho** que agora não marca mais porque atingiu tudo o que podia. O 2 ali era o 250 da prata

Comment: aqui quando visito as minhas completas, carrega a barra "estourada" e depois que roda o JS, ela some. Faz parte das maravilhas do client-side rendering :D